# ¿Cómo sumar los n enteros con hilos?

Tags: java, hilos

Este es el ejercicio  Dado un entero *n* divisible por 5, calcula la suma de todos los enteros desde 1 hasta *n*, ambos incluidos. Divide el trabajo en, al menos, 5 hilos..
Mi idea es dividir el número entre 5 y cada pedazo enviarlo a una clase derivada de thread, pero necesito un sexto hilo que sume el resultado de los anteriores pero ya no sé cómo hacerlo.

```
public class Numero {

    private int numero;

    public Numero(int numero) {
        this.numero = numero;
    }

    public int getNumero() {
        return numero;
    }

    public synchronized int particiones(int numero) {
        int resultado = 0;
        if (numero % 5 == 0) {
            resultado = numero / 5;
        }
        return resultado;
    }
}
```

Luego os pongo solo un par de clases hilo para que veaís la idea, no os voy a poner los 5

```
public class Hilo1 extends Thread {

    private Numero suma;

    public Hilo1(Numero suma) {
        this.suma = suma;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        int num = suma.particiones(suma.getNumero());
        int sum =0;
        for (int i = 1; i <= num; i++) {
             sum += i;
        }
    }

public class Hilo2 extends Thread {

    private Numero suma;

    public Hilo2(Numero suma) {
        this.suma = suma;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        int num = suma.particiones(suma.getNumero());
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i = num + 1; i <= num * 2; i++) {
            sum += i;
        }
    }
```

El hilo 3 va desde `num * 2 + 1` a `num * 3` etc.
El problema viene cuando he de sumar el resultado de los otros hilos en 1.

Comment: Veo un problema en tu logica.. no tenes que construir 5 clases que sean cada una un hilo.. tenes que construir una sola clase, y dispararla 5 veces ;) y usar lockeos para obtener los valores y cosas asi ;)

Comment: Lo que vos estas haciendo ahi no son 5 hilos... son 5 clases distintas...

Comment: pues no se me ocurre otra forma, otra manera es poniendo que sume a intervalos pero los intervalos lo tengo que meter a mano en el main, y parece que queda feo

Comment: supongamos que a cada thread le pasas un batch de 5 numeros, y cuando termina ese thread devuelve la suma.. el main se puede ocupar de sumar los totales.. puede que cada thread se dispare varias veces.. pero lo unico que hace el thread es sumar desde el numero inicio, hasta el numero final que vos le decis...

Comment: ea pero la idea seria que ese numero inicial y final sea automatico como lo he echo en mis clases y no que lo meta a pelo en elmain. porque si lo meto a pelo en el main ya he encntrado como hacerlo

Comment: Eso ultimo que decis no lo entiendo.. esos numeros inicial y final los va a ir calculando el main a medida que cada hilo los necesite...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aquí te deje una implementación muy básica de como funcionaría lo que necesitas. Ya tu podrás modificarla de acuerdo a tus necesidades. Deberás calcular que valores de un arreglo se le pasaran a cada hilo dependiendo del valor n que pusiste en el enunciado de tu ejercicio. Espero te sirva y te de una idea de como funcionan los hilos. También puedes modificar la implementación y en lugar de pasar un arreglo pasas los números inicial y final.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        int numbers1[] = new int[]{1,2,3,4,5};
        int numbers2[] = new int[]{6,7,8,9,10};
        Hilo h1 = new Hilo(numbers1);
        Hilo h2 = new Hilo(numbers2);

        h1.run();
        h2.run();

        h1.join();
        h2.join();

        int total = h1.getTotal() + h2.getTotal();
        System.out.println("Total: " + total);
    }
}

class Hilo extends Thread {
    private int numbers[];
    private int total;

    public Hilo(int numbers[]) {
        this.numbers = numbers;
    }

    public void run() {
        for(int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
            total += numbers[i];
        }
    }

    public int getTotal() {
        return this.total;
    }

}
```